# How to solve run time error method failed?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a piece of code in vba but I'm still getting this error whenever I try to run it.
When I use debug the cursor on top of the 2nd line says "partDocument1 = Nothing"
Here's the code:

```
  Set partDocument1 = documents1.item(Right(activeComponentWorksheet.cells(R, tem).Value, nameLength))
            Set part1 = partDocument1.Part
            Set body1 = part1.Bodies.item("PartBody")
            selection1.Add body1
```

I'm just trying to create a part from the excel values by using macros. Could anyone explain why would this error happen?

[image: "Run-time error '-214746.... Method 'SetImpl' of object 'Documents' failed."]

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that first line and check the value of `activeComponentWorksheet.cells(R, tem).Value` and `nameLength` - Are they what you expect? If not, what are the vales of `R` and `tem`? Are they what you expect?

Comment: Yes, so I just put a breakpoint on the code and it shows the R value that I want and the tem value that I need. But the partDocument1 = Nothing

Comment: And the value of `nameLength`?

Comment: nameLength has the value that I need as well.

Comment: Are you sure `documents1` is the right document?

Comment: Yes, so documents1 is a series of files which I need to be designed by using vba. Through that code block that I wrote in the question, it should simply grab that certain file with the R, tem, and namelength values.

Comment: Then i guess this question has nowhere near enough information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error message "Run time error method failed" is a general error message that can occur for a variety of reasons in VBA. It typically indicates that an operation that the code is trying to perform has failed, but without more information about the error and the specific line of code that is causing the issue, it is difficult to determine the exact cause of the problem.

One possible cause of this error in the provided code snippet is that the documents1.item(Right(activeComponentWorksheet.cells(R, tem).Value, nameLength)) method call is returning Nothing. This means that the item being passed as the argument to the method is not found in the documents1 collection. This will cause the subsequent Set part1 = partDocument1.Part and Set body1 = part1.Bodies.item("PartBody") line of code to throw the "Run time error method failed" error.

You can try to debug the error by adding some debug information and check if the variable partDocument1 is not equal to nothing before the error is thrown.

```
If partDocument1 Is Nothing Then
   Debug.Print "partDocument1 is not found"
End If
```

You can also try to check if the value of the Right(activeComponentWorksheet.cells(R, tem).Value, nameLength) is matching with the value that you are expecting.

It's also possible that the problem is related to the activeComponentWorksheet.cells(R, tem).Value cell value or with the nameLength variable, it may be referencing a non-existent cell or it may contain a value that is not expected.

It's also possible that the problem is with the Bodies.item("PartBody") method, it may be that the body is not present or the name passed to the method is not correct.

These are some possible causes of the problem, but without more information about the specific environment and configuration of the code, it is difficult to provide a more specific solution.

Comment: Yeah, I checked with the debug function and it says that "partDocument1.Part" = "Object variable or With block variable not set." It's the only one that it's saying that because the other variables contain the proper value.